# Mixture of measure

Tags: measure-theory

There is a measure theory theorem I don't even understand the formulation... Here it goes :

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space and $(W,P)$ a measurable space.

Suppose that for every $x \in X$, $\lambda_x$ is a measure on $P$, s.t for every fixed $E \in P$, $\lambda_x(E)$ is S-measurable in x, and for $E \in P$, define :
\begin{align}\lambda(E) = \int \lambda_x(E)d\mu(x).\end{align}

1)What is exactly the pre-image and image of $\lambda_x$ ? Since it's a measure I assume the image is $\mathbb{R}$ and the parameter $E$ suggest that the pre-image is $P$. But the $d\mu(x)$ suggest the measure takes $x$ in parameter. Which is in contradiction with : "$\lambda_x$ is a measure on $P$".

2)"$\lambda_x(E)$ is S-measurable in x". The pre-image has to be $X$ then ... IF it is, then what role $E$ is actually playing in this ? If it's not a parameter.

I need your lights !!

Thanks !

Comment: This doesn't make sense:  if $\lambda_x$ is a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra, $P$, then $\lambda_x(E)\in\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, it's not an element of $S$.

Comment: This is really confusing. And this result is used later in the book ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to make perfect sense: for every $x$ in $X$ and every $E$ in $P$, $\lambda_x(E)$ is a nonnegative real number or $+\infty$. Fix some $E$ in $P$ and define the function $f:X\to[0,+\infty]$ by $f(x)=\lambda_x(E)$ for every $x$ in $X$. Then the assumption is that $f$ is measurable for the sigma-algebras $S$ and $\mathcal B([0,+\infty])$, and the RHS of the displayed identity is $$\int_Xf\mathrm d\mu=\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu(x)=\int_X\lambda_x(E)\mathrm d\mu(x).$$ Any mysteries left?